# Rstudio is not running on Ubuntu 16.04. [qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display]

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

I followed the installation instructions available on [R](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) and [Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209074748-Installing-RStudio-Desktop-on-Ubuntu-16-04-LTS) websites, but I haven't been able to run rstudio on my Ubuntu 16.04.

These are the results I get when I call rstudio from the terminal are given below. I have no idea of how to fix this issue.

Cheers!

```
$ sudo rstudio
```

The output:

*qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)*

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Why do you call it with `sudo`? RStudio does not require `root` privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I had this morning the same problem. I tried the solution proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/902774).
Actually, I first uninstall my Rstudio installation:

`sudo apt remove --purge rstudio`

Then, I ran:

```
sudo apt-cache search qt5 | grep 'X11 extras'
```

resulting in:

```
libqt5x11extras5 - Qt 5 X11 extras
libqt5x11extras5-dev - Qt 5 X11 extras development files
```

As suggested in the link, and following the lines above, I then ran:

```
sudo apt install libqt5x11extras5
```

(I didn't even tried to install `libqt5x11extras5-dev`). After completed, I restart.
And again, I tried to install my Rstudio packages (deb file, download from Rstudio website).
When finished, I just tried to open it from my menu, and it worked. Let's see if everything is ok then...

I hope this may be useful for some!

(for information, my system: Lubuntu 18.04 installed on a flash-usb)